# X over Ethernet (use laptops as additional screen) in Linux? (maxivista)?

Tags: remote-desktop, ethernet

Welcome,

Does anybody know Linux application what allow me to use laptop's as additional screen using Ethernet ?

In Windows environment there is application called "maxivista" You can look at homepage to see what it can do.

http://www.maxivista.com/demo.htm

Everything is going over standard 100 mbit ethernet.

I'm wondering could i do something like this in ubuntu, or combined ubuntu - to windows ?

For example create "fake" X screen and display it to other computer?

If someone know any idea, please share :)

Answer (score 3):

Never tried it but you could check out this project:

http://dmx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It even runs on SGI Irix! What a blast from the past ;-)

Comment: That project looks dead from few years.

Comment: It may appear dead but it is still available in the ubuntu repos.  You can search YouTube to see demos of it.  It may be old but it still might do the job.

Comment: Not quite a slick as being able to drag a window from one monitor to another but you could use http://shifter.devloop.org.uk/ to handle moving an application from one screen to another and Synergy+ or x2x to handle mouse and keyboard input on slave machine.